# Increment and decrement operators in one statement in C

Tags: c, increment, decrement

I know it is theoretically undefined behavior and of course bad style. This is the example of a school (I am not the pupil).
But why do I get 7 (example a) resp. 1 (example b) out of this operation:

Online example:
https://onlinegdb.com/B172lj8k8

**a:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    printf("%d; i=%d", ++i + i++, i);
    return 0;
}
```

**b:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    printf("%d; i=%d", ++i - i++, i);
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion the output should be 6 and 2.

1. Execute i++, yield 2, increment i
2. Execute ++i yield 4
3. Additon 2 + 4

The other example should be 4 - 2.

Exexcuting the increment in a statement seems to yield the result of the increment immediately, no matter if it is postfix or prefix, which is odd. Or do I get it wrong totally?

Comment: As you know that it is UB, where "everything" can happen, why are you wondering at all?

Comment: I am wondering how a beginner should know that and the teacher expects an answer. And no matter how I calculate in my head, I never get to 7

Comment: Because it's undefined behavior. The compiler is allowed to do anything with the code, the compiler can just optimize it to `int main() { printf("%d; i=%d", 7, 4); }` and [this most probably happens](https://godbolt.org/z/YEsmZF), but I don't know compiler options used in onlinegdb. There is no calculation. There is no sense.

Comment: "I know it is theoretically undefined behavior " is not compatible with "In my opinion the output should be"   . If you think there should be certain output, it shows you do not understand that it is undefined

Comment: @M.M What does the compiler do, to get to 7 resp 1? Just wondering, what is going on here?

Comment: Use you debugger to step through the assembler.  Since your code has UB, only you can trace through to find out what is happening in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order in which the arguments passed to a function are evaluated is not specified, and the order of evaluating the operants of `+` is unspecified, too.

So in `printf("%d %d", i+1, i-1)`, for example, you cannot rely on the order of evaluation of the arguments; `i+1` might be evaluated *after* `i-1`, actually; You will not recognise, since the evaluation of the one does not effect the result of the other.

In conjunction with "side effects" like the post-increment `i++`, however, the effect of incrementing `i` at a specific point in time might influence the result of other evaluations based on `i`. Therefore, it is "undefined behaviour" in C, if a variable is used more than once in an expression and a side effect changes its value (formally, to be precise, if there is no sequence point in between).